# How to use ADF parameters in a Kusto command activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to use an ADF parameter as a value inside my Kusto query in the `command` tab.

If I use the value `percentage cpu` manually in my query, it will run just fine.

```
KustoTable
| where tolower(CounterName) has "percentage cpu"
```

But if I change my query to this one below, nothing happens.

What is the proper way to use Kusto command + parameters?

```
KustoTable
| where tolower(CounterName) has "{counter}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter should be given as `"@{pipeline().parameters.<parameter-name>}"` in Kusto Query.

```
KustoTable
| where tolower(CounterName) has "@{pipeline().parameters.counter}"
```

I tried this with sample query. Below are the steps.

- Parameter named `counter` is created in ADF pipeline.

[image]

- Then in query or command text box,  `add dynamic content` is clicked and sample query is typed in the text box.

**sample query:**

```
.show tables
| where TableName has "@{pipeline().parameters.counter}"
```

[image]

When pipeline is run, it got executed successfully.

Comment: Thank you, It worked! In case I want to use any function. How should I apply in the parameter? `@{trim(pipeline().parameters.<parameter-name>)}` or `@{pipeline().parameters.trim(<parameter-name>)}`?

Comment: you will have to use this `@{trim(pipeline().parameters.<parameter-name>)}`. `pipeline().parameters.<parameter-name>` will give the parameter value. Functions should be applied on this expression only.